# SQL Syntax - Why do we need to list individual fields in an SQL group-by statement?

Tags: sql

My understanding of using summary functions in SQL is that each field in the select statement that doesn't use a summary function, should be listed in the `group by` statement.

```
select a, b, c, sum(n) as sum_of_n
from table
group by a, b, c
```

My question is, why do we need to list the fields?  Shouldn't the SQL syntax parser be implemented in a way that we can just tell it to `group` and it can figure out the groups based on whichever fields are in the `select` and aren't using summary functions?:

```
select a, b, c, sum(n) as sum_of_n
from table
group
```

I feel like I'm unnecessarily repeating myself when I write SQL code.  What circumstances exist where we would not want it to automatically figure this out, or where it couldn't automatically figure this out?

Comment: One such circumstance would be when your rdbms is MySQL.

Comment: @DanBracuk, except MySQL will let you omit the `GROUP BY`... most often to your own detriment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decrease the chances of errors in your statement. Explicitly spelling out the `GROUP BY` columns helps to ensure that the user wrote would they intended to write. You might be surprised at the number of posts that show up on Stackoverflow in which the user is grouping on columns that make no sense, but they have no idea why they aren't getting the data that they expect.

Also, consider the scenario where a user might want to group on more columns than are actually in the `SELECT` statement. For example, if I wanted the average of the most money that my customers have spent then I might write something like this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(max_amt)
FROM (SELECT MAX(amt) FROM Invoices GROUP BY customer_id) SQ
```

In this case I can't simply use `GROUP`, I need to spell out the column(s) on which I'm grouping. The SQL engine could allow the user to explicitly list columns, but use a default if they are not listed, but then the chances of bugs drastically increases.

One way to think of it is like strongly typed programming languages. Making the programmer explicitly spell things out decreases the chance of bugs popping up because the engine made an assumption that the programmer didn't expect.

Comment: Oh I'm not surprised on the number of poorly formed queries that show up - I've seen them firsthand.

Comment: I can't personally remember the last time I needed to write a query like that but I guess it would be occasionally useful.  I think a better designed query language would let you optionally specify the fields you want to group on if you don't want all non-summary function fields grouped on.  Perhaps even syntax like `group by *` where the `*` only refers to non-summary function fields. I think there's only so much hand-holding you can do and having people state their intention twice doesn't necessarily simplify the process nor make it 'easier' to get the intended results.

Answer (score 0):

This is required to determine explicitly how do you want to group the records because, for example, you may use columns for grouping that are not listed in result set.

However, there are RDBMS which allow to not specify `GROUP BY` clause using aggregate functions like MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction would be that 'it is what it is' =)
But on thinking it through, the reason TSQL works like this is because the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` are two distinct parts of all the operations going on in the query.
This might not be the best example, but it does show that you can `GROUP` on different (well, 'more') fields than you are actually `SELECT`ing.

```
SELECT brand = Convert(varchar(100), ''), model = Convert(varchar(100), ''), some_number = Convert(int, 0)
  INTO #test
 WHERE 1 = 2

INSERT #test (brand, model, some_number)
VALUES ('Ford', 'Focus', 10),
       ('Ford', 'Focus', 25),
       ('Ford', 'Kagu', 23),
       ('DMC', '12', 88)


SELECT brand, model, MAX(some_number)
  FROM #test
  GROUP BY brand, model

SELECT brand, MAX(some_number)
  FROM #test
  GROUP BY brand, model
```

Not all RDBMS's are like this, e.g. MySQL allows for omitting fields from the `GROUP BY` that are nevertheless in the `SELECT` part. From what I've seen, it then picks a random value ('there is no such a thing as an implicit first') and uses that in the `SELECT` .. I think, my knowledge on MySQL is rather limited but I've seen some examples here and there and they always confused me as I'm used to the strict requirement of TSQL you just described.

Comment: And it seems max beat me to it =)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can group by your columns in a different order than select

```
select a, b, c, sum(d)
from table
group by c,a,b
```

Also a lot of DBs allow you to skip column names, you can just specify which columns are going to be included in the group by using select position

```
select a, b, c, sum(d)
from table
group by 3,1,2
```

Comment: I'm not certain that field ordinal would make a difference in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It saves time and typos at least when you don't type column names

Comment: I meant switching the order of the fields in the `GROUP BY`. Totally agree on ordinal reference though! I'd go nuts if I couldn't `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14` and end up posting questions like OP's.

Comment: I see, I've seen some requirements _order in select_ and _order of group by_ is different.